# how to view the footer template text box of child grid in nested grid view?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, jquery, gridview

I am new to dot net. i am trying to create nested grid,now I am struck up to view the footer template text box of child grid in nested grid view and I tried in google but there is no such a solutions. whether it is possible to view or not? if possible means how to do? please guide me.

Thanks in Advance,
With Regards,
Shibin G

Comment: Did you look at [nested gridview how to get inner gridview footer text](http://forums.asp.net/t/1629282.aspx?How+to+create+a+flipcart+like+panel+for+showing+products+in+gridview)?

Comment: On which event you want to get the textbox of nested grd? like on edit or on any button click etc ? also please show your code

Answer (score 0):

You just need set the attribute of the gridview: "ShowFooter=true".

```
Example code  <asp:GridView ID="grwDetail1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="PartItem_Id, Manufacturer_Id" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowHeader="true"   ShowFooter="true"   CssClass="Grid"/>
```